# What is the smallest $a\ge 0$ that satisfies $\sqrt{(x+cy)^2+y^2}\le a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the smallest $a\ge 0$ that satisfies $\sqrt{(x+cy)^2+y^2}\le a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? Where $x,y,c\in\mathbb{R}$

My strategy is to manipulate $\sqrt{(x+cy)^2+y^2}$ so it is less than or equal to $f(c)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

So $\sqrt{(x+cy)^2+y^2} = \sqrt{x^2+2cxy+c^2y^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2cxy+y^2(c^2+1)}\le$ ?? I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: who is $c$ in your inequality?

Comment: $c$ is a real number

Comment: suggestion: you can express $x$ and $y$ as polar coordinates, and you get only the polar angle showing up. All you have to do is to find the extrema of a function of one variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy will not work. $\frac{\sqrt{(x+cy)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ is not a function of $c$ only, so your $f$ will have to be some bounding function. But it will only provide you with *some* upper bound, whereas this problem requires the least upper bound.

Instead, note that if you multiply both sides of the inequality by some positive constant $k$, you get $\sqrt{(kx+cky)^2+(ky)^2}\le a\sqrt{(kx)x^2+(ky)^2}$. Thus, if $a$ works for any $(x, y)$, it also works for $(kx, ky)$. This means that we can restrict our attention to $x, y$ with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, and $a$ will be the minimum value of $\sqrt{(x+cy)^2+y^2}$ subject to this restriction. Since the square root is an increasing function, this minimum occurs at the same point as the minimum of $(x+cy)^2+y^2$

As Chip suggests, all points with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ have the form $x = \cos \theta, y = \sin \theta$ for some $\theta$, so now we need to minimize

$$(\cos \theta +c\sin \theta)^2+\sin^2 \theta = 1 + c\sin 2\theta + c^2\sin^2\theta$$

Take the derivative, set it to 0. Take the solution with the lowest function value. Take the square root to find $a$.